# Import selected columns from a tab delimited text file

Tags: import, text

I have a very huge file (1GB) from which I desire to import only the 5th column. It is a tab delimited text file with a `.txt` extension. Can you please help me with this?

I generally use `Import["filename.txt","Table"]` to import my files, but now, I don't want the whole file, which takes a long time to load.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux you could use this simple solution.

**Linux Shell**

From the shell:

`$cat myfile.txt | cut -f 5 > col5.txt`

Then import into Mathematica as usual.

```
data = Import["col5.txt","Table"]
```

**ReadList**

This can be condensed to one `ReadList` command.

```
data = ReadList["!cat myfile.txt | cut -f 5"];
```

Comment: Or `awk '{print $5}' myfile.txt` :)

Comment: @rm-rf Yes, there is a beauty in the simplicity of awk :)

Comment: oh I didn't know we can incorporate linux commands in mathematica. I use cut command all the time. instead of cat and then piping it, we can directly use the cut command on the file as well. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Works perfectly on windows as well using http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/ or by installing msysgit :)

Comment: @image_doctor How can I use this solution if 'my file.txt' is given as `ToFileName[...]`? Also, how is the command for reading the first four columns only?

Comment: @Valerio: if you compute the filename or have it in a variable, you can build the command you give to `ReadList` with e.g. `StringJoin`: `ReadList[StringJoin["!cat ",FileNameJoin[{...}]," | cat -f 5"]]`. Note that `ToFileName` still works but is marked to be deprecated in favor of `FileNameJoin`.

Answer (score 11):

You might try this:

```
Import["data.txt", {"Data", All, 5}]
```

If you want to load only the fifth column of the first two lines you can run this:

```
Import["data.txt", {"Data", {1, 2}, 5}]
```

You can find more about this [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportASpreadsheet.html).

**Update**

Some testing on a relatively small data file (12MB) might prove that this is not really the solution you're after. It seems that it takes much more time to load just one column (~130 seconds) than to load the entire file with `Import["data.txt","Table"]` (~4 seconds).

Comment: yes, I tried this from mathematica documentation and had the time issue. That was the reason behind this post. I missed to mention that.

Comment: ReadList is almost always faster then Import.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Unix-like system or have installed `cut` or `awk` on other systems letting these do the extraction is most probably the most efficient way to solve your problem. If for some reason you are looking for a Mathematica-only way here is one:

```
readColumn[filename_, colnum_, numcols_, numlinesperchunk_Integer: 500] := 
  Module[{
    str = OpenRead[filename],
    res = {""}, data
  },
  data = Reap[
  While[Length[res] > 0, 
   Sow[res = 
     ReadList[str, Table[Real, {numcols}], numlinesperchunk][[All,colnum]]]
   ]
  ][[2]];
  Close[str];
  Flatten[data]
]
```

to extract the 5th out of 6 columns you would use:

```
readColumn[filename,5,6]
```

using the 4th argument you can play around with `numlinesperchunk` for further optimization. Note that there is a tradeoff between maximal speed (very large values for `numlinesperchunk`) and minimal memory usage (low values for `numlinesperchunk`). For largish files I would expect a good value might be some hundreds of lines per chunk, but your milage may vary...

This might look a bit complicated for such a simple tasks but it tries to be efficient not only concerning runtimes but especially concerning memory which usually is a larger problem when importing large data files into Mathematica. Note that the code here is very similar to that for my answer to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15206/169), where you find other ways to do similar things even more efficient at the price of more involved programming in Java and also some more background information...