# Importing several huge files with headers & footers

Tags: list-manipulation, import, data, performance-tuning

having here several files in ASCII format

http://ge.tt/91rv0Jf/v/0

I want to import, while removing headers and footers and then join the several lists.

```
strm = OpenRead[".omf"]
Skip[strm, Record, 38, NullRecords  -> True];
mydata = ReadList[strm, Number, 7500*3, RecordLists -> True]
Close[strm];
```

This correctly removes headers and footers, so I don't know to combine this to a

```
alldata = Map[Import[ ], FileNames[]]
```

like command to import all files in the directory.

```
data = Import[#, "Table", HeaderLines -> 38, NumData ->  7500*3, 
AllNumeric -> False, TrailerLines -> 2] & /@ FileNames[]
```

This works for importing all files, but the footers (or trailers?) are not removed, output:

```
{{ 755205.327 391367.272 126872.268},{ 638270.884 407054.202 408065.135},{ 621838.43 593464.262 -26779.3974},{ 792199.887 301929.715 -144422.249},{ 827047.904 221093.933 -81909.9342},<<7493>>,{ 638270.884 407054.202 408065.135},
{ 755205.327 391367.272 126872.268},{# End: Data Text},{# End: Segment}}
```

HeaderLines isn't even mentioned in the Math7.0 Doc. In principle I only need the 3 column in every single .omf file

```
column3 = mydata[[All, 3]];
```

and those columns from every single file should than be arranged to a columnlenght X filenumber matrix list. Is it possible to apply this already when doing *Import* or *OpenRead* to save memory as this is just a example and the real files will be in the 2 digit GB range? Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `Skip` and `Readlist` in a `Module` and make it a function:

```
importfile[name_] := Module[{strm, mydata},
  strm = OpenRead[name];
  Skip[strm, Record, 38, NullRecords -> True];
  mydata = ReadList[strm, Number, 7500*3, RecordLists -> True];
  Close[strm];
  mydata
]

importfile@"f1-Oxs_TimeDriver-Magnetization-000000-0000028.omf"
```

This will also likely be faster then import.

Alternatively, if you want to use `Import`, or in the case that your files are different lengths, you can import and then use `Drop` to remove the last 2 elements.

```
data = Drop[
    Import[#, "Table", HeaderLines -> 38, NumData -> 7500*3, 
     AllNumeric -> False, TrailerLines -> 2], -2] & /@ FileNames[]
```

If you want only the third column of very large files see: [Reading periodic elements from a large file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/reading-periodic-elements-from-a-large-file)

Answer (score 2):

A simplistic,if slightly inefficient, solution might be:

```
data = Import[#,"Table"][[39;;-3]]&/@Filenames[];
```

Other options might involve, 'Cases', 'Choices', `Drop`, `Take`.

For example:

```
data = Drop[Drop[Import[#,"Table"],38],-2]&/@Filenames[];
```

If you are using a Linux derivative or something like cygwin on Windows, then this is an efficient solution for reading only the third field from your files ( assumes whitespace separated data, other delimiters can be specified ).

```
data= ReadList["!head --lines=-2 " <>#<> " | tail --lines=+39 | cut -f 3 "]& /@ FileNames[]
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted a follow up question to this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24289/significant-platform-dependent-efficiency-when-importing-data