# Import large amount of data with time stamps

Tags: import, data-format, performance-tuning

I have a large data file (150 000 lines) which I want to import in Mathematica. The first few lines look like this

```
28/04/2013 20:01:36.18  2.5013E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.26  2.5013E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.32  2.5013E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.35  2.5011E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.48  2.5011E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.53  2.5011E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.60  2.5008E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.64  2.5008E-2   W
28/04/2013 20:01:36.70  2.5008E-2   W
```

The first column is the date, second is the time, third is the measured value and the last is the unit of measurements.
I want to make `ListPlot` of the data, where the x axis should be time since the start in proper formatting (e. g. HH:MM) and the y axis the measured value. Of course, the importing has to be done very efficiently, due to the large number of lines. So, I guess I should use ReadList, but I don't know how to Mathematica what I want.

Update in response of the comments below

I used this code

```
s = OpenRead["filename.dat"];
data = ReadList[s, {Record, Number, Record}, RecordSeparators -> {"\t","\n"}]
```

which gives me this

```
{{"28/04/2013 20:01:36.18", 0.025013, "W"},
{"28/04/2013 20:01:36.26", 0.025013, "W"},
{"28/04/2013 20:01:36.32", 0.025013, "W"}....}
```

Now, the problem is how to plot this the way I want.

Comment: First, open a stream, eg. `s = OpenRead["data.txt"]`, and read in every line as a string, `ReadList[s, Record]`, yes?

Comment: You can read the first two columns as string and convert to date lists with `DateList`. With that result you can then use e.g. `DateListPlot`. As converting with `DateList` might be relatively slow and your date format is fixed, I would suggest to use a `StringReplace` + `ToExpression` approach for improved performance.  I think answers to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15206/169) question will also be relevant, although your file seems to rather be large but not yet huge.

Comment: Unless you have a screen 150,000 pixels wide you or Mathematica have to drop quite a few measurements to be able to show them on the screen. You may want to consider how you want to do that. `Downsample` is a possibility.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I will use `Joined->True`, so that is not a problem, but thanks for the tip

Comment: `Joined` isn't really a solution. My point was that if you have 150,000 points or line segments, the screen won't be able to show them all, so this kind of input is a bit of overkill.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You have got a point.

Comment: `Downsample` is only available in Mathematica 9. Is there any alternative for 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you requested performance I would avoid `Import` and `DateList` and use `ReadList` and `AbsoluteTime`.

```
format = {Number, Character, Number, Character, Number, Number, 
    Character, Number, Character, Number, Number, Word};

data = {AbsoluteTime[{#5, #3, #1, #6, #8, #10}], ##11} & @@@ ReadList["data.txt", format];
```

`"data.txt"` is of course your data file.
The `Slot`s are used to reorder expression into the form needed by `AbsoluteTime`.

You can then convert the timestamps into delta from start like this (in-place modification):

```
data[[All, 1]] -= data[[1, 1]];
```

This entire process takes under a second with a 150,000 line file on my machine.

Comment: This indeed seems to be faster.

Comment: But wait a minite, the second command doesn't give me the difference between any entry and the first, but between two consecutive entries. And also my imported data looks like this `{{3.57626821343000000000000*10^9, 9.1454*10^-6, "W"}, {3.57626821346000000000000*10^9, 9.1454*10^-6, "W"},...`

Comment: @phidelio Pardon me, I apparently misread the question; for some reason I thought you wanted sequential differences.  Corrected.  As for the data, the values are absolute time in seconds from the beginning of the *Mathematica* epoch.  After processing they are time in seconds from the start.  Is this a problem for you, and if so, how?

Comment: sorry, I solved this quite easily after subtracting the initial value

Answer (score 6):

`Import` is very well able to handle this format. As a demonstration I use its nephew `ImportString` to deal with the few lines from your example:

```
data =
 ImportString[
  "28/04/2013 20:01:36.18  2.5013E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.26  2.5013E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.32  2.5013E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.35  2.5011E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.48  2.5011E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.53  2.5011E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.60  2.5008E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.64  2.5008E-2   W
  28/04/2013 20:01:36.70  2.5008E-2   W", "Data"]
```

> {{"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.18", 0.025013, "W"}, {"28/04/2013",
>      "20:01:36.26", 0.025013, "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.32", 
>     0.025013, "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.35", 0.025011, 
>     "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.48", 0.025011, "W"}, {"28/04/2013", 
>     "20:01:36.53", 0.025011, "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.60", 
>     0.025008, "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.64", 0.025008, 
>     "W"}, {"28/04/2013", "20:01:36.70", 0.025008, "W"}}

Convert dates and times to `DateList`

```
times = (DateList[#1 <> " " <> #2]) & @@@ data[[All, {1, 2}]]
```

> {{2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 36.18}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 
>     36.26}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 36.32}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 
>     36.35}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 36.48}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 
>     36.53}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 36.6}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 
>     36.64}, {2013, 4, 28, 20, 1, 36.7}}

Timing with respect to the start:

```
timeDifs = (DateDifference[times[[1]], #, "Second"] & /@ times)[[All, 1]]
```

> {0., 0.08, 0.14, 0.17, 0.3, 0.35, 0.42, 0.46, 0.52}

```
values = data[[All, 3]]
```

> {0.025013, 0.025013, 0.025013, 0.025011, 0.025011, 0.025011, \
>   0.025008, 0.025008, 0.025008}

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{timeDifs, values}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly what I wanted. The `import` command needed to much time, so I replaced it with `data = ReadList[s, {Record, Record, Number,Record}, RecordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", "\n"}];`