# Importing large data without using Import

Tags: import

I have around 240 files with lots of data, I have been using `Import[]` to import these data for further processing. But as my simulations are growing bigger, I am having lots of difficulty importing them, my computer is freezing and lagging (my  computer has 6GB RAM). I was wondering if there is a better (less memory intensive) option to import these files?

I have been using the following loop command to import this data as strings and then converting them to numbers

```
Rawdata = Table[
     s = ToString[j];
     Import["C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Run 6 new z=45 sigma =0.845\\pinocchio." <>
          StringTake[s,2] <> "." <> StringDrop[s,2] <> ".example.catalog.out",
          "Data"],
     {j, 200000, 420000, 1000}];
```

Is there an analogous way to import the files without using so much memory?

Comment: Could you please format your code using linebreaks? It is very hard to read at the moment. Did you search the site for already existing solutions yet?

Comment: I found the commands Get and Dump, but I am not sure how to apply a loop statement to it.

Comment: Please search the site for "Import large" and take a look at the listed threads.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found anything that specifically answers this question.

Comment: Look at OpenRead and ReadList

Comment: Plus, there's a missing quote in the code you provided.

Comment: @Algohi I tried using ReadList["file",String], but my computer completely froze, I checked that with ReadList the memory usage was much more compared to Import. Perhaps, I will import them in parts and Concatenate them. But still the data is stored in the memory, and my computer starts to act sluggishly. Is there a way, I can erase the memory once I have the data concatenated?

Comment: I would load the data files into a database like MySQL and then connect to it from Mathematica with DatabaseLink. MySQL's "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ..." is incredibly fast.

Comment: I guess it will be difficult to help you unless you provide a minimal working example.

Comment: what are you talking about importing as strings and converting to numbers?  I don,t see that in your code at all.

Comment: You can use ReadList to read line-by-line or by blocks (use its third parameter). Erasing memory: just unset (`=.`) the variable you want to clear, or use ClearAll or Remove.

Comment: do you generate the data with mathematica and reread it with mathematica? If yes, then use `Dump` and `Get` as you suggested (although I think `Export[filename,expression,"MX"]` is slightly cleaner). Anyway, if you want the data to be accessable with other programs you could also look at specific file formats like HDF5 which are at least partially supported from Mathematica and will be a much better choice to store large numeric arrays, even a whole collection in one file...

Comment: @YvesKlett The actual data is around 250 MB and contains over 10^6 lines of numbers. A small working example will defeat the purpose of this question as I can very well import a small data list using either ReadList or Import.

Comment: @AlbertRetey No, it's generated from an N-body simulation like code.

Comment: and the code writes the presumably numeric results into text files? Can you change that and make that code save something else? It certainly is possible to read in these text files, but it might in total consume more time than changing the data format (in case that is possible)...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I have been trying to break up my code into cells and after I evaluate one cell and transfer the result to a variable into the next cell, I clear the variable of the previous cell. But this doesn't seem to work, my RAM consumption keeps increasing even though I clear the unnecessary variable, is there a way out?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I have the output files in .out format, but the problem is, each output file has some unnecessary text which I want to remove, that's why all this hassle. Perhaps, I could go into the simulation itself and modify it so that it doesn't outputs those text. Hmmm!

Comment: concerning memory: do you know about `$HistoryLength=0`? if you don't do that Mathematica will remember all output you ever generated in a session. concerning import: if changing the simulation, I'd consider another format for your files, text is just not a very good encoding for numeric data. Other than that, you might find this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15206/169) and answers to it helpful. If sticking with text, you can read lines with ReadList and type String instead of BindaryReadList as in the answer...

Comment: A MWE would still be tremendously useful to show and test alternative approaches. Those you could benchmark with your data and give feedback on their performance. But without the exact specs for your files this depends on too much speculation.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is or can be coerced into a rectangular array of machine `Integer`, `Real`, or `Complex` numbers (all the same type), then you can use `ToPackedArray` to reduce the amount of memory required, as well as make operations on the data faster.  One might have hoped that `Import` would do this automatically, but it doesn't.

You can use `ByteCount` to see how much memory a variable is consuming.

Those operations, as well as `PackedArrayQ` and `FromPackedArray` require `` Needs["Developer`"] `` to load them.

Simple example:

```
Needs["Developer`"]
dat=ExportString[RandomReal[1,{1000,1000}],"Table"];
ImportString[dat,"Table"]//ByteCount
```

> ```
> 24208200
> ```

```
ImportString[dat,"Table"]//ToPackedArray//ByteCount
```

> ```
> 8000152
> ```

Comment: Does someone know how to put a backquote inside backquotes?  I can't get just one backquote to show up for Needs["Developer`"] when inside backquotes.

Comment: use `<code>  .. </code>` instead of back ticks..

Comment: @george2079 Thanks!