# Import columns from a long .txt file

Tags: import

I have to import columns 1,2,3, and 6 from a long (2 * 10^5 rows) file with this structure:

```
{-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, -0.561626, 5.08542, -28.8257, -17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9}
{-17762.7, -8181.8, 25999.8, -0.560809, 4.04628, 1.31158, -17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9}
{-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, -0.561326, 0.0121829, 17.303178201333805208, -17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9}
```

I use `Import` as follows for column 6:

```
Import[file, {"Table", "Data", All, 6}, "FieldSeparators" -> {"{", ",", "}"}]
```

and analogously for the other. It works but it takes forever. How can I speed up the process?

Comment: have you seen [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15206/169) and answers to it? It is probably not exactly the same but I think the answers should give you all the information you need...

Comment: You could preprocess the file with [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) before reading it into Mathematica.

Comment: Have you tried `ReadList["filename", Expression][[All, {1, 2, 3, 6}]]`?

Answer (score 3):

For very efficient processing you can combine the [awk command-line utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) with `ReadList`: the first extracts the desired columns without doing any conversions, and the second performs conversions only on the extracted columns.

```
ReadList["!awk -F '[{},]' '{print $2 $3 $4 $7}' filename.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True]
```

> {{-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, -28.8257}, {-17762.7, -8181.8, 25999.8,
>      1.31158}, {-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, 17.30317820133380521}}

Notice that we're extracting columns 2, 3, 4, 7 instead of 1, 2, 3, 6 because there is an offset coming from the initial curly brace {.

A general reading function would be

```
read[filename_String, columns_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] := 
  ReadList["!awk -F '[{},]' '{print $" <> 
           StringRiffle[ToString /@ (columns + 1), " $"] <> 
           "}' " <> filename,
    Number, RecordLists -> True]

read["filename.txt", {1, 2, 3, 6}]
```

> {{-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, -28.8257}, {-17762.7, -8181.8,
>      25999.8, 1.31158}, {-17763.1, -8182.33, 26000.9, 
>     17.30317820133380521}}

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the file one line at a time:

```
str = OpenRead["file"];
col6 = {};
While[True,
  l = Read[str];
  If[l == EndOfFile, Break[]];
  AppendTo[col6, l[[6]]];
  ];

col6
(* {-28.8257, 1.31158, 17.30317820133380521} *)
```

Comment: `Read` can be quite slow if memory serves. Try `ReadList[str, String, 1][[1]]` instead for a faster version. E.g.: [read-list vs read/read line](https://mresources.github.io/tutorial/mathematica-programming/assorted-tricks/import-and-readlist.html)