# Stream reading 1000 times faster in Python

Tags: streams

I have a 26GB CSV. I want to extract all the rows that have data for a specific sensor. In Mathematica I write:

```
stream = OpenRead[my26GBFile];
Reap[Block[{line},
  line = ReadLine[stream];
  While[
    StringQ[line],
    If[StringContainsQ[line, "Sensor123"], Sow[line]]
    line = ReadLine[stream]
  ]
]]
```

I let it run overnight because it takes at least an hour. I wrote the following in Python and it ran in about 2 minutes. I would not expect the performance difference to be that great. Anyone have insight into what's happening and how to get better performance in Mathematica?

```python
import csv

with open(my26GBFile, 'r') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

  with open(newCSVFile, 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
      if 'Sensor123' in line:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
      else:
        continue

  new_file.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm curious, can you time `grep Sensor123 my26GBFile > newCSVFile` and does the result exactly match the output of MMA and Python? Thanks

Comment: @Bill 
Using grep in terminal: 2:21.
Using Python: 3:08.
Using Mathematica: Maybe 100 minutes

Comment: Have you tried `FindList`? https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/FindList.html

Comment: Thank you for that timing. I'm surprised that Python is that close to grep. If you have a spare couple of hours I'd be interested in what Mathematica's `AbsoluteTiming` would give. Maybe if you showed us what a typical line with Sensor123 was and a typical line without then someone might be able to show a line of MMA that would be 3x faster.

Comment: That was it! @azerbajdzan, would you post your response as an answer? It took 19s in Mathematica using `FindList` beating out Terminal and Python by almost 10x

Comment: @Bill , Example line: "\"2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z\",\"SENSOR123\",\"43.60736846923828\""
and the next line might be something like
"\"2020-01-28T00:03:00.000Z\",\"SENSOR456\",\"43.53498077392578\""

Comment: MaxMemoryUsed for FindList gives 40MB for a 3GB file, which is great

Comment: I think the deeper reason for the huge differences is that python's `open` by default has buffering switched on which Mathematica's `OpenRead` doesn't offer buffering. You can add buffering on your own if necessary which will help a lot, you will find several answers on this site showing the details, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15206/169). But if what you need to do can be achieved by `FindList` that is certainly the preferred solution...

Answer (score 19):

[`FindList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindList.html) is meant to deal with such tasks. Not sure whether it works with all types of files but for plaintext files like in the case of CSV file it should work.

Comment: FindList (3s) was much faster than grep (33s) or python (70s) for a case insensitive search (30150 out of 3133378 lines) of a 3GB csv.

Answer (score 1):

With python you have GIL, which makes a lot of things run slower.

You could use a library like `polars` to speed things up.
e.g.

```python
import polars as pl
def cell(filepath):
    df = pl.read_csv()
    return df.to_dicts() # turns dataframe into list of dict
```