# Importing specific columns of a .txt file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have text delimited file, with data in four columns.

How to use `ReadList` to extract only the first and the fourth column.

Comment: (I am not sure why this is getting dinged.)  I don't know how to do this either with `ReadList`. Anyway, it may be just as easy to read the whole data set with `ReadList`, then take the columns with `dataReadIn[[All,{1,4}]]` Otherwise it could be a job for `OpenRead`, `Read`, `Skip`, etc.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/plot-data-from-txt-file)

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/import-selected-columns-from-a-tab-delimited-text-file)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what exactly is a "text delimited file"? Is it like a ["character-separated values (.csv)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)?

Comment: Also related: [(17841)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17841/121)