# How to calculate the mean of a set of a plotted points?

Tags: plotting

I am interested to calculate the mean of a certain set of points of a graphed curve. Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a (minimal) example?

Comment: Have you tried using `Mean`? You should provide a minimal working example of what you are trying to accomplish, otherwise you will hardly get any answer

Comment: I have a graph with a set of coordinates (points) that show a certain curvature (e.g. maximum). I want to specify these points in the "mean" in order to calculate the mean of these points.

Comment: What is the input (a plot?) and expected output? Where are you stuck because I'm assuming you are familiar with `Mean`.

Comment: Este não volta mais... Há uma semana não voltou pra ver a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Here a example:

```
res[x_] := x^2 + 5
x = Range[-1, 10]
Mean[res[#] & /@ x] // N
points = Transpose[{x, res[x]}];
Plot[res[x], {x, -1, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]}]
```

> {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>
> 37.1667

[image]

Comment: Actually, I don't have a certain function. However, the points are given in a .txt file. 

How can we include a certain condition (e.g. if condition) to calculate the mean of a certain interval inside a column from the text file?

Comment: See this: [Page1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/plot-data-from-txt-file)

Comment: Other: [Page2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/import-selected-columns-from-a-tab-delimited-text-file)